# What's the replacement for floatLabel="never"?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Angular Material search input field that is defined like this in an Angular app. The `floatLabel="never"` property on the `mat-form-field` keeps the placeholder from floating in the current app.

```html
    <mat-form-field floatLabel="never">
        <input matInput #searchInput="matInput"
               type="text" 
               placeholder="Search"
               [value]="s.searchStore.query"
               (focus)="onSearchFocus()" 
               autocomplete="off" #input/>
        <mat-icon [color]="searchInput.focused ? 'primary' : ''" matSuffix>search</mat-icon>
    </mat-form-field>
```

However in Angular 15 `floatLabel="never"` is deprecated.

What should we use in its place?

Comment: If you don't want a floating label then why set it in first place? placeholder stays in place by default. so simply remove `floatLabel="never"`

Comment: floatLabel is used with `<mat-label>` not with placehoder

Comment: OH OK!!  Cool!!  In the older implementation the placeholder floated ... good to know :)

Comment: Here's an example from [form-field in latest Angular Material version](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#form-field-label) just in case :)

Answer (score -2):

I recently updated angular from 14 to 16. I believe in angular 15 and 16, "never" has been depreciated and we have to use "always"